# How to use NHibernate.Burrow with winform/desktop application?

Tags: winforms, nhibernate, nhibernate-burrow

1) Is it possible to use Burrow with winforms application or WPF application?

2) Are there any samples how to configure Burrow with winforms app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if it is possible - you should not. Burrow uses HttpModule to configure ISession, ISessionFactory lifetime.

You won't get anything usefull from burrow except implementation of DAO objects and some base classes for entities. I think you better move the source code of required parts in your application and use them.

Answer (score 1):

What about using

```
new NHibernate.Burrow.BurrowFramework.InitWorkSpace();
new NHibernate.Burrow.BurrowFramework.CloseWorkSpace();
```

These methods create and destroy the Session without using httpModule. So it can be used in unittests where u cannot supply the module. => what about winforms apps? The question is still opened